# How to print link text in twig?

Tags: 8, theming

I've attached file to a node with Media module. I have custom `templates/file/file-link.html.twig` file, which is rendering the download link with `{{ link }}` tag.

`{{ devel_dump(link) }}` outputs this:

[image]

**I need to print `File name` as pure text without any link rendering for some cases**.

I've tried `{{ link.text }}`, `{{ link.text.string }}` and other options, but none of them gave me what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but when I tried `{{ link.text }}` one more time - it worked great!

Maybe I forgot to clear cache, when I used it for the first time, I don't know, but I think I should leave this answer for anyone who will search for it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a render array and you need to use `link['#text']` here (sorry if I'm on the wrong track).

Edit: If `{{ link.text }}` worked on subsequent tries, then my answer is definitely wrong, and the reason for your problem was probably related to caching or something.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know why, but `{{ link.text }}` worked, when I tried it again.

Comment: That's really odd, and my only guess is that it might have been a caching problem?

Comment: Could be, but I always clear it before looking for any change. Anyway, thanks a lot for such a quick response for my problem.